# Wrap lightning-tab inside custom LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-tabset

I wan't to offload tab loading (and separate concerns) from my lightning-tabset container.

When I naively wrap my components I get errors which I find rather hard to parse.

```
<template>
    <template if:true={dpc.tables}>
        <lightning-tabset variant="scoped">
            <template for:each={dpc.tables} for:item="table">
                <c-some-table-sheet table={table} key={table}>
                </c-some-table-sheet>
            </template>
        </lightning-tabset>
    </template>
</template>
```

someTableSheet:

```
<template>
    <lightning-tab label={table} key={key} >
        One Content {table}
    </lightning-tab>
</template>
```

I suspect that there's something to do with violating DOM contract here?

Edit: Not really able to get any meaningful error, but JS debugger pauses on this exception `TypeError: b.loadContent is not a function` at `_showTabContentForTabValue(a) {` function.

Comment: It works when you bring `tab` itself as a direct child of `for:each`? I am curious what you mean by offloading tab loading as `tab` is already lazy loading IIRC.

Answer (score 2):

The `<lightning-tabset>` expect `<lightning-tab>` as slotted element. By wrapping the `<lightning-tab>` with your own component you breaking this contract.

The `<lightning-tabset>` throws an error `_showTabContentForTabValue` because it is trying to communicate with your wrapper component thinking it's a standard `<lightning-tab>`.